# Android mediaplayer release onstop sound

Tags: android, memory-management, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Hi I want to press buttons that each play a sound but I'm having trouble releasing mediaplayer when I'm done. So eventually too many instances of mediaplayer are open and sound crashes, here is my code:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Media;


namespace soundplayer

{
    [Activity (Label = "soundplayer", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
            Button button2 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button2);

            button1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create (this, Resource.Raw.sound01);
                mediaPlayer.Start ();   
             };

            button2.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create (this, Resource.Raw.sound02);
                mediaPlayer.Start ();
            };
         }


        public void onStop(){
        mediaPlayer.Stop ();
        mediaPlayer.Release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        }

        }

    }
```

---

I tried stepping through my program and noticed that after mediaPlayer.Start (); my program never bothers to access onStop. Is there a way to make it do that or another solution to my problem. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

First of all `onStop()` is called only when activity is stopped.

In your case, to stop and release the media player, you need to implement `OnCompletionListener` for your mediaplayer. In your onCompletion method release the media player as follows

```
public void onCompletion(){
        mediaPlayer.Stop();
        mediaPlayer.Release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

Do not create 2 media players, just create one globally and it shall do the job for you. Make sure you don't start another mediaplayer while one is in playing mode. You can do that by using the following

```
if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: So I just replace the onStop with onCompletion?
Where do I put the if statement. Sorry I'm super new to this, just really trying to get this app working to show to a friend

Comment: First implement `OnCompletionListener ` in your activity then add unimplemented method it shall have the onCompletion method added. Add the code which I have written in that method.

Comment: I'm really not sure how to implement it, could you share the code for that please. I'm also not sure where to add the method.

Comment: I still need help if anyone can

Comment: Iqbal can you just show me exactly where and how to insert your code into mine to make my program work

Comment: Did you implement `onCompletionListener` for the button? After doing it you will have to override the `onCompletion()` method.  In that method paste the code as in my answer.